Create bullet list using `paste0` within rmarkdown document to generate pdf
I am trying to create a list using this code in Rmarkdown:
```{r}
vars_col <- c(letters[1:5])
model_latent_vars <- c(LETTERS[1:5])
```

Variables list:  

`r paste0("  - ", vars_col, " &mdash; ", model_latent_vars, collapse = "  \\newline  ")`

The result is not the desired one, I would like to obtain a bullet list, however with this solution only the first line gets the bullet.


If you use collapse=" \\newline", the generated tex code looks like,
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  a --- A\newline  - b --- B\newline  - c --- C\newline  - d ---
  D\newline  - e --- E
\end{itemize}

Hence you are getting only one bullet point with rest of the content in a new line.
To get the desired output, you need to use collapse="\n" instead.
```{r}
vars_col <- c(letters[1:5])
model_latent_vars <- c(LETTERS[1:5])
```

Variables list:  

`r paste0("  - ", vars_col, " &mdash; ", model_latent_vars, collapse = "\n")`

